# meteor direct user to a url when session value is set

Tags: node.js, url, redirect, meteor

I am using meteor.js.

How can I direct the client to a url without the click of a button. I am retrieving a url from the server and have this url set in session a variable.

```
 Session.set('grSignInUrl', result)
//result =  http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=6mLjmfytrCj695y98S
 window.location = result;
```

Only when there is a value in this session, I would like the users browser to direct them to this url. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page and Deps.autorun

Comment: Do you mean Tracker.autorun?

Comment: window.location = result; //this works perfectly. I dont need to store it in a session. I just wait for the value to be returned to the client.

Comment: yea, obviously mistake

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but something like this:

```
Tracker.autorun = function() {

    var link = Session.get('grSignInUrl');
    if (link) {
        window.location = link;
    }
}
```

The autorun will be called each time the session variable changes.